# General help with 'report' chapter numbering and bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, numbering, chapters, report

I've slightly 'inherited' a set up from another document and it's not behaving as I'd wish right now... Here is the preamble,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[nodayofweek]{datetime}
\longdate
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{pcr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat*{\section}{\Huge\bfseries}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{frame=single,language=C++,captionpos=b,aboveskip=10pt,belowskip=0pt,basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,breaklines=true}

\floatstyle{plain} % optionally change the style of the new float
\newfloat{code}{H}{myc}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

%\renewcommand\refname{Bibliography}

\title{\Huge{\textbf{blah blah blah blah}}}
\date{}
\author{me\\
       \{me\}@xyz.com\\ \\
}
\usepackage[nottoc,numbib]{tocbibind}
```

What I want to get is simply this kind of set up,

> **Chapter 1**
>
> Introduction
>
> blah blah blah blah
>
> ***1.1 New Section***
>
> etc

I would also like the Bibliography to NOT appear as another chapter as it seems to right now. But to be un-numbered... but to appear in the table of contents.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.

Comment: Haha. Sure. No problems. I should just add I think I've solved the general numbering... but the bibliography is still giving me problems!

Comment: Do you want a bibliography heading of the level `section` and unnumbered?

Comment: Yes please marco... and appearing as 'Bibliography' at the end of the table of contents...